# How to copy conditional formulas across sections of a worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I have data laid out within mini tables within a singular worksheet. See picture

I need to conditionally format the whole row (within the minitable) based on a cell value within the row.

For example, for table U, I would highlight A4:E4 based on the value of B.

The problem is, when I copy the conditional formatting to table T, it is still referencing column B, not column G as I want it to. I have to do this many times (50+), so to fix it manually would take unreasonably long (7 conditional formats per mini table, 50+ tables). Any ideas?

[image: Table]

Comment: It would help to see your formula, but my first guess is you need absolute rather than relative references. i.e. use `$B` instead of `B`

Comment: The formula, for example for table U, would be ="$B4"="TWL W/G", applied to the range =$A$4:$E$20, so that any rows containing "TWL W/G" would be highlighted. When I copy this over to table T, it still references B, when I want it to reference G. I think the absolute reference is needed in order to highlight the entire row within Table U... not sure how to get around that.

Comment: $B is an absolute reference to B, so it remains B when you copy.  B is a column, so that has no effect on any rows.  (A and E also have absolute references, so that will still be the range when you copy.)  Eliminate the absolute reference to B if you want the formula to adjust to G..

Comment: hlinhd, I think Excell's conditional formatting varies a lot depending on the version, but I tried to get this to work and ran into the same problem you're having.  The $B is required in your formula, or only column A gets the format.  That makes *some* sense, if you think about it.  Given that the $B is required, when you paste the formats from Table U into Table T, you get formatting that depends on what's in column B.  So I think the only solution is to edit the formula after you Paste Special into Table T, when the whole area is selected. That saves a *little* time and effort.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all your mini tables are the same width, and there are no gaps (or only a fixed width gap) between them, you can use a single conditional format formula like this, applied to cells `$A$4:$E$4`:

```
=OFFSET($A4, 0, 5 * QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A4)-1, 5) + 1) = "TWL W/G"
```

You should then be able to use the format painter tool to copy the conditional format down the rest of the first table, and across the other mini tables. You shouldn't need any further editing.

This works by calculating which mini table is being formatted (from the column of the cell being evaluated), and hence which cell the test string should be compared against.

`$A4` is the starting point for the offset.  It is an absolute reference to column A, but has a relative row reference, so when you copy the format to other rows, they will be formatted separately.

The `QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A4)-1, 5)` part calculates which table the cell being evaluated is in, assuming each table is 5 columns wide.  `A4` is a totally relative reference, so it gets replaced for each cell you copy the format to.

The `5 * QUOTIENT() + 1` part selects the 2nd column of the correct table (assuming they are all 5 columns wide).  Change the 5s if your tables use a different number of columns, or the `+ 1` if you need to test a different column within the table.

Comment: That works well.  Great answer.

Comment: It's a useful formula to fix the issue and you deserve 10 :-) .

Answer (score -2):

*Follow these steps:*

**First approach:**

1. Select required data range in Table U.
2. Click Conditional Format, New Rule, Use Formula to determine which
   cell to format.
3. In Edit the Rule Description write this formula `=B4 = B4.`
4. Apply the format what you wish to and finish with OK.
5. Select conditional-formatted range in Table U, and Copy.
6. Select target range in Table T, and click Paste Special.
7. In Paste Option category click Formats then OK.

**Second approach:**

1. Copy a cell from the Table U to blank cell.
2. Select copied cell, Click Conditional Format, Manage Rules option.
3. From Select Show formatting rules for, select This Worksheet.
4. For Rule on Table U, change the Applies to match data range.
5. Select the data range in Table T to apply the format.
6. Click OK.

**NB:**

After you copy conditional format, check Manage Rule for Table T, now you find the Formula is `=G4 = G4`. Here, Excel justifies the 'Copy Format' and also adjustes the Target data range.

But remember while using this, Excel will format those Rows also which doesn't matches the B4 value.

Comment: The first approach does not work correctly. Yes, the rule in Table T is changed to G4=G4, but since B4=B4 (or G4=G4) is **always true**, every cell in both tables receives the format, no matter what value is in column B (or G) for that row. OP wants formatting to be applied if column B (or G for Table T) is the specific text "TWL W/G". So Table T should **not** receive the formatting, if the answer works correctly. That's because no cell in column G contains "TWL W/G".

Comment: As far my understanding, while copy format Excel justifies the original  rule, but since the rule changes to G4=G4 so that It applies format on Table T. But you raised a good point, let me find out that how could Excel justify  B4=B4 for table T also. :-)

Comment: One tricky method can accomplish the OP's job. While formatting A4:E4 in table U the formula should $G4<>B4. Then copy  B4 and put cell pointer into either G4 or even G4:G9 then Paste Special and Formats. This will not format the counter part in Table T and when OP check Table T, will find rule changed  to G4<>G4. Just check it. :-)

Comment: No, that doesn't work either, for a similar reason to the first approach.  B4<>B4 or G4<>G4 is **always false**, no matter what the value of B4 is, so the formatting will *never* be applied.